# How to plotting dots according to XY coordinates in android ?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and i just want to represent dots on a 2D map (not Google Maps) according to the XY coordinates in a database. When I click a particular dot I need to display text on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: canvas.drawPoint(float x, float y, Paint paint) method. Initialize a new Paint object, and set the color and size, etc.

If you want to add text, use the drawPosText (char[] text, int index, int count, float[] pos, Paint paint) method.

See this article for info on how to use canvas: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html